# How to make image size adapt to row height in an html table

Tags: html, css, image, css-tables, thunderbird

I am trying to make a robust html signature to use in Thunderbird. By robust I mean it must look right not just in Thunderbird, but in other mail clients that I send the mail to. I test this with Gmail, for example.

The layout is quite simple, it's something like this:

Best Regards

<  PPPPPPPP  >  | Pieka Grobbelaar

<  PPPPPPPP  >  | 082 111 0000

<  PPPPPPPP  >  | pieka@mycompany.co.za

The "PPP" is a picture (the company logo). So I want to achieve this layout by using a 1-row, 2 column table, and by putting the picture in the first cell and the text in the second.

Now, I can set the image size in pixels, but that's problematic because somehow different mail clients handle the font size differently (this might be because of the way the Thunderbird packages the mail before sending - who knows? ). But I want to keep the logo the same height as the three lines next to it.

So, I want the table to "stretch" to the height of the 3 lines in the second cell, and then I want the image to stretch itself to the height of the row, while keeping its aspect ratio.

so, this is the basic frame (I think):

```
<table>
 <tr >
  <td >
   <p ><img  src ="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0...."></p>
  </td>
  <td >
   <p >Pieka Grobbelaar</p>
   <p >082 111 0000 </p>
   <p >pieka@mycompany.co.za</p>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

What must I add top get the behavior I want?

Comment: `I am trying to make a robust html signature to use in Thunderbird.` This is simply not possible, as senders don't have full control about how exactly HTML in mails is rendered. Many different mail clients use different HTML engines and even with the same engines allow different parts of HTML and CSS for e.g. security reasons. Simply avoid such things altogether, most people don't care about icons and images and marketing in signatures anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classic way :
to avoid image to be taken into size calculation , you need to take it out of the flow via `position:absolute;` .

to size it to the `height` of the row , make the parent `td` in `position:relative;` so it becomes the reference. `height:100%` will basicly be where to start from.

`table-layout:fixed` and a `width` on `table` and only one `td` will finish the setting. em is a value easier to manage to fit average max text length.

Here is a possible example to demonstrate the idea. Inline style should be understood

```html
<table style="table-layout:fixed;width: 20em;border:solid;margin:auto">
  <tr>
    <td style="position:relative;width:40%">
      <p>
        <img style="position:absolute;max-width:100%;max-height:100%;top:0;" src="https://dummyimage.com/400">
        <!-- demo img is a 1:1 ratio you need to tune table and td widthS -->
      </p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Pieka Grobbelaar</p>
      <p>082 111 0000 </p>
      <p>pieka@mycompany.co.za</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>
<table style="table-layout:fixed;width: 20em;border:solid;margin:auto">
  <tr>
    <td style="position:relative;width:40%">
      <p>
        <img style="position:absolute;max-width:100%;max-height:100%;top:0;" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x400">
        <!-- demo img is a 1:33 ratio you need to tune table and td widthS -->
      </p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>Pieka Grobbelaar</p>
      <p>082 111 0000 </p>
      <p>CSS Land</p>
      <p>pieka@mycompany.co.za</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

hope these hints work for you issue.