# HTML - How to define a specific area for vertical scroll while ensuring flanking images remain stationary?

Tags: html, css

My code is something like this:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><img "leftBorder"></td>
      <td ID="BODY">
        <grid>
          <img1/>
          <img2/>
          <etc>
      </td>
      <td><img "rightBorder"></td>
```

How do I fix the position of the border images so that only the BODY is scrollable vertically?

Comment: make grid absolute position , height:100%;overflow:auto and  #BODY position: relative. if grid is out of the flow via absolute, it will not stretch the table. similar method : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62490317/how-to-make-image-size-adapt-to-row-height-in-an-html-table/62490455#62490455 ... why table in the first place ?

Comment: table is because im having trouble floating left/rightBorder img snug to the body and it responds correctly when resized
its not a problem for the table to resize vertically as long as it doesnt reposition the border images

Comment: okay, dislay:table is also avalaible and no need to use an HTML table structure nowdays . display has also plenty other features. Using a table will bring much more troubles to deal with later on. if left and rightborders are design , backgrounds or border-image can also do the job. What you try to do was the 90's method....

Comment: thankyou greatly for your replies. hmm ok so I should scrap the table and reformat the border images a way that will both incorporate position:fixed attribute and also align them flush to the sides of the BODY. I was having trouble doing that with divs. I'm just worried when it comes to resolutions of different sizes, when resizing (zooming) the page the border images dont stick to the body
doing this reminds me why i left programming behind haha

Comment: ...and/or scrap position:fixed and look into backgrounds/border-image as you say. thansk for advice#

Answer (score 0):

you could try to put leftBorder and rightBorder to position: sticky or fixed. And on BODY you put, overflow-y: scroll

Comment: fix one thng and another brakes :(
now the scrolling works but the left image wont float to the right snug to the body :(

Comment: how can I reposition the leftBorder to now align to the BODY's left border without offsetting with margin values because that does not react well when resized?